# Having Trouble with MySQL Primary Key and adding Index (Error #1064)

Tags: mysql, indexing, key

```
CREATE TABLE registers(
User_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
IP INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL INDEX,
Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL)
```

I get this error:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX,
    Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL)' at line 3*

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to get replies so soon. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

To define inline indexes in a CREATE TABLE statement, you will need to place it on a separate ['create definition'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) line:

```
CREATE TABLE registers(
  User_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  IP INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  INDEX(IP),
  Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e21d4)

You can also place the index definition outside of the table definition, [like so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a015b):

```
CREATE INDEX IX_registers_ip ON registers(IP);
```

It is regarded as good practice to name the index, so that it can be referenced exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead - in MySQL syntax the INDEX definition cannot be included in the field definition:

```
CREATE TABLE registers(
User_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
IP INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
INDEX `ip_1` (`ip`)
)
```

Alternatively - sometimes preferred for readability you can create the index in a separate statement after you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE registers(
User_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
IP INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ip_1 ON registers (ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your synatx must be:

```
CREATE TABLE registers(
User_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
IP INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
Success TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Time_Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
INDEX (IP )
)
```

For more information about the create table statement see the official [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)